# Is there an infinite J-group?

Tags: gr.group-theory

For a group $G$ let $\operatorname{Sub}(G)$ be the lattice of all its subgroups. 
A **subgroup interval** is an interval in the lattice $\operatorname{Sub}(G)$.

A group $G$ is called a **J-group** iff $\operatorname{Sub}(G)$ satisfies [Jordan-Dedekind chain condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Jordan.E2.80.93Dedekind_chain_condition). Sometimes there is another definition of Jordan-Dedekind chain condition. But I mean the wikipedia definition which is the second definition in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/890247/138171).

**Question.** Is there an infinite J-group?

---

**Question origin**: A very old monograph (about lattice of subgroups, 1950s) by Michio Suzuki said that it is unknown if there are any infinite J-groups.

Comment: Does it work for $G = \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: no. let $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\Bbb Z$.

Comment: how about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: Yes it seems working for the first part. I edit the first question out, Because  my question is about J-groups which require a normal series.

Comment: Five edits of the question in less than an hour makes it hard to hit a moving target

Comment: The title is the target. Other edits are marginal. Also I deleted a trivial question.

Comment: the trivial question was: what if all $⊴$ in the question are replaced with $\le$? Then then answer  is yes and Tarski monster group is the example as commented above.

Comment: p.177 of Garrett Birkhoff's **Lattice theory** might be relevant. Firstly he defines a J-group to be a group such that the lattice $Sub(G)$ satisfies the Jordan-Dedekind condition and, second, records a result of Iwasawa to the effect that a finite group is a $J$-group if and only if it is supersolvable. I realise that this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @NickGill: So my definition above is not correct? really I'm not sure if by *series*, it means [subnormal series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_series#Normal_series.2C_subnormal_series). Or if $n$ is fixed? in the first version of the question I the ⊴ were ≤ but Tarski Monster group is a simple answer so I the monograph meant subnormal series.

Comment: Since $[[A_i,A_{i+1}]]$ has 2 elements and $A_i$ is normal in $A_{i+1}$, doesn't it immediately follow that $A_{i+1}/A_i$ is cyclic of prime order?

Comment: @YCor: yes. And it seems this immediately proves that $G$ is finite. If so I have serious about understanding the definition of a J-group. This is what I have note down from monograph's definition: If $U$ and $V$ are subgroups of $G$ and $U\supseteq V$ there exists a series
$$U=H_0\supset H_1\supset\dots\supset H_r=V$$
such that $H_i$ is a maximal subgroup of $H_{i-1}$ for $i=1,\dots, r$. (I think $r$ is fixed and I'm not sure what the author means by series, probably he meant a finite sequence)

Comment: Well, in the 50s Tarski monsters were indeed unknown... and Suzuki's question was equivalent to the question on whether an infinite finitely generated group can have a maximal subgroup that is finite, which is solved by Olshanskii's examples.

Comment: With the given definition of J-group, every such group is finite and every subgroup is subnormal. These are exactly the finite nilpotent groups.

Comment: I am voting to close since the question has undergone so many changes that it is hard to trace the comments and see what is going on. For instance, the version of the question that is current as I type mentions subgroup intervals, but then these do not seem to be used in the definition of a J-group. Compare the last two comments just above this one.